# My yearly display of morning glories haven't bloomed

Tags: flowers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I encourage morning glories to bloom?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-encourage-morning-glories-to-bloom)

I did see the other answers for morning glories not blooming but didnt find that it answered my question fully.
 Every year i plant either nasturtiums or morning glories in the large window planter in fron tof my house. They always require very little care and bloom profusely. This year I did everything the same, have not fertilized and sun exposure and soil is the same but no blooms. 
 The only thing i can think of is that I used mostly seeds collected from last years plants. Is there a process I am unaware of as to storing the old seeds or?? the vines and leaves are otherwise healthy.
thanks!
let me know if i should just go back to nasturtiums next year.. I miss my flower blooms climbing all around the front window!

Comment: If your area is experiencing drought conditions this may affect flowering.  But morning glory vines are tough, almost weedy....